# Border only on half of the div

Tags: html, css

I have a div inside my nav bar, where I have my logo. This div excels the nav bar and shows off into the wrapper. I'll add an image to show you exactly what I mean:

[image: My nav bar]

So, that image on the left is my logo.
The nav, as you can see, has a border-bottom property, to show a tiny red line, so what I want is to also show that border in the logo div, but only in the part that separates the nav with the wrapper (normal blue with dark blue).
This is my code:

**HTML**

```
    <nav>
    <a href="index.php"><img src="resources/img/logo.png" id="logo"></a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="portfolio.php">Portfolio</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
    nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #38434d;
    height: 99%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid darkred;
    clear: both;
}

#logo {
    max-width: 7%;
    background: #38434d;
    float: left;
    padding: .2em;
    margin: .1em 0 0 3em;
}
```

So, what can I do to show only the bottom border of my logo div?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you do a http://jsfiddle.net/ of the full thing?

Comment: This will be very hard to make it cross-browser safe due to relative dimensions and percentage heights. That way, you never now for sure how far the logo goes out of the nav bar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach, is to style the `<a>` element, rather than the contained `<img>`, and use a pseudo-element whose borders we can style:

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #38434d;
  height: 99%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid darkred;
  clear: both;
}
/* keeping the same styling, with the addition of the position
   in order to position the pseudo-element */
nav > a {
  max-width: 7%;
  background: #38434d;
  float: left;
  padding: .2em;
  margin: .1em 0 0 3em;
  position: relative;
}
nav > a img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 60px;
}
nav > a::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50%;
  /* styling the border of the pseudo-element the same as the nav element: */
  border: 1px solid darkred;
  /* 'removing' the top-border */
  border-top-width: 0;
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="index.php">
    <img src="resources/img/logo.png" id="logo">
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="portfolio.php">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Just as a side-note: you might want to consider using a more specific selector rather than `nav a` which targets all anchor tags within the navigation.

Comment: Agreed, but I prefer not to throw a new `id` on elements in simple demonstrations (though obviously the OP can). In this case it seems safe enough.

Comment: Of course but you could simply use `nav > a` instead. Currently the anchor tag containing `Portfolio` is styled as well.

Comment: Sorry for the noise but it would be great if you could change `nav a::after` also :-)

Comment: Oh, thanks! It worked fine on my design, I had also to set a padding and a margin of 0, but it actually worked!! Thanks a lot, @DavidThomas !!!!